# Wordpress: links to single pages direct to localhost

Tags: wordpress

When a user clicks on the post links after reading a single post, the link directs to a localhost URL. This only happens on my oldest posts. Is there a way to reset the post links or at least renew them?

Example:

1) Go to [this page](http://www.gonesouthblog.com/rotorua-to-opotiki/) and scroll to the post navigation after the text

2) Click on one of the links that directs to an adjacent post

3) Look at the URL after clicking (WTF!?!)

```
<nav>
        <p>
            <?php $prev_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true ); ?>
            <?php $next_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false ); ?>

            <?php if ( !empty( $prev_post ) ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $prev_post->guid; ?>">&laquo; <?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( !empty( $prev_post ) and !empty( $next_post ) ): ?>
            <?php echo ' | '; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( !empty( $next_post ) ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $next_post->guid; ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?> &raquo;</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
    </nav>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please add the code generating those links.

Comment: I added the code used on the single.php. This works fine for newer posts. It's just not working for the older posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link generating code uses the `guid` field, which is neither reliable as you can clearly see nor does it take into account the link structure set for the website. Use `get_permalink` instead, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>">&laquo; <?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database might have old links, especially if it was moved locally to a live site. I normally use [this php script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) when transitioning because it will catch all the records. you'll just need to search for **localhost** and replace with **www.gonesouthblog.com**. Just make sure you delete that script after from the server after it has run.